# Quack - the revolutionary new data structure

Tags: c++, binary-search

I was having a chat with a friend about data structures (as you do), and that, and his love of portmanteaus meant that he came up with a `Quack` - A queue and a stack, stuck together in the dumbest way, as it just gives you a tuple of the front and back items. I thought that it might be at least possibly useful if it was ordered, and therefore would pair up the largest and smallest items in the structure.

If anyone can tell me a use for it, or even if it's already a thing in any incarnation (other than `std::list`, to some degree, I guess), I'd be pleased, as the only thing that we could come up with was matching good players on the same team as bad ones for a training .

As well as this, I spent longer than I'd like to say implementing a binary search, with the expectation of it being really quick, but it's quite a bit slower than a linear search, and I was wondering why. My guess was that the cpu can do better branch prediction on linear when it's on sorted data, but that's just a hunch.

> ```
> Linear search - ~320ms to insert 10,000 random items
> Binary search - ~860ms to insert 10,000 random items
>
> Random is a simple call to rand() from cstdlib
> Time is gotten from std::chrono::high_resolution_clock
> ```

Anyway, that's already too much waffle. As well as what I've already mentioned, general practice pointers would be appreciated. Bear in mind this is using C++0x. The `print()` function is just there so that I could get the algorithms right, and I just left it in for completeness sake. I'm planning on deleting it.

```cpp
#ifndef QUACK_H_
#define QUACK_H_

#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <tuple>

#include <stdexcept>

#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Quack
{
    private:
        std::list<T> data;
        typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator iter;

    public:
        Quack();

        void insert(T dat);
        std::tuple<T, T> poppop();
void print();
        inline bool empty(){return data.empty();};
    private:
        iter binarySearch(T toFind, iter min, iter max);
        iter linearSearch(T toFind);
};


template <class T>
void Quack<T>::print()
{
    for(iter i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << *i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
Quack<T>::Quack()
{
}

template <class T>
void Quack<T>::insert(T dat)
{
    if(data.empty())
    {
        data.push_back(dat);
    }
    else
    {
        data.insert(linearSearch(dat), dat);
        //data.insert(binarySearch(dat, data.begin(), data.end()), dat);
    }
}

template <class T>
std::tuple<T, T> Quack<T>::poppop()
{
    if(data.empty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Empty quack");
    }else if(data.size() == 1)
    {
        throw std::range_error("One item left in the quack - Cannot form tuple");
    }else
    {
        std::tuple<T, T> d(data.front(), data.back());
        data.pop_front();
        data.pop_back();
        return d;
    }

}

template <class T>
typename std::list<T>::iterator Quack<T>::linearSearch(T toFind)
{
    if(data.empty())
    {
        return data.begin();
    }

    for(iter it = data.begin(); it != data.end();)
    {
        if(toFind > *it)
        {
            it++;
        }else
        {
            return it;
        }
    }
    return data.end();
}

template <class T>
typename std::list<T>::iterator Quack<T>::binarySearch(T toFind, iter min, iter max)
{
    if(data.empty())
    {
        return data.begin();
    }

    int length = std::distance(min, max);
    length /= 2;

    iter midpoint = min;
    std::advance(midpoint, length);

    if(midpoint == data.begin())
    {
        if(toFind > *midpoint)
        {
            return ++midpoint;
        }else
        {
            return midpoint;
        }
    }

    if(*midpoint > toFind)
    {
        iter temp = midpoint;
        temp--;
        if(*temp < toFind)
        {
            return midpoint;
        }
        if(midpoint != data.end())
        {
            midpoint--;
        }
        return binarySearch(toFind, min, midpoint);
    }else if(*midpoint < toFind)
    {
        iter temp = midpoint;
        temp++;
        if(*temp > toFind || temp == data.end())
        {
            return temp;
        }
        if(midpoint != data.begin())
        {
            midpoint++;
        }
        return binarySearch(toFind, midpoint, max);

    }else
    {
        return midpoint;
    }
}
#endif //QUACK_H_
```

Comment: Your binary search is slow because this isn't a random-access container: `std::distance` is O(n) and so is `std::advance` for non-random-access containers. So of course, on the end, your binaty search becomes dramatically slow.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [dequeue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue). Coming up with simple revolutionary ideas *is hard* these days.

Comment: @peterph you know, that does sound like a much more helpful thing. Well, they don't have my catchy name for it. Or the sorting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the standard library a bit better instead of reinventing half of the wheel:

- `std::tuple<T, T>` does not sound like a bad idea, but I would probably return `std::array<T, 2u>` instead to make it obvious that there is no way the two elements could be of a different type.
- For example, `linearSearch` can be trivially reimplementend with `std::find`:

  ```
  template <class T>
  typename std::list<T>::iterator Quack<T>::linearSearch(T toFind)
  {
      return std::find(std::begin(data), std::end(data), toFind);
  }
  ```

  As an added bonus, it makes it clear that `std::end(data)` is returned when the list is empty (`list::begin` returns `list::end` when `list::empty` is `true`).
- By the way, the standard library function `std::lower_bound` returns exactly the value you need to use insert, so `Quack::insert` could be written as:

  ```
  template <class T>
  void Quack<T>::insert(T dat)
  {
      data.insert(
          std::lower_bound(std::begin(data), std::end(data), dat),
          dat
      );
  }
  ```
- That said, this is not optimal either. If you want to maintain a sorted list of values, you probably want to use an `std::multiset` or a similar structure that already keeps its data sorted for you.

Never forget that the standard library is your friend and probably always has *the* algorithm you need to perform a known task on a linear set of data :)

---

That was it for the standard library usage. Now let's go for another round of comments about other parts of the code:

- `typedef` is a bit old-fashioned. You coud use C++11's [type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) instead. I find their order more consistent with assignment and aliasing in the rest of the language and as an added bonus, they can be templated:

  ```
  using iter = typename std::list<T>::iterator;
  ```
- Range-based `for` loops are awesome. Let's use lots of them! Instead of this:

  ```
  for(iter i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); i++)
  {
      std::cout << *i << " ";
  }
  ```

  You will probably want to write that:

  ```
  for (const T& elem: data)
  {
      std::cout << elem << " ";
  }
  ```
- While `iter` works, it could be a good idea to name it `iterator`  and add a bunch of other subtypes so that your class works more like the standard library containers.
- That said, instead of a container, you might want your class to be *container adapter* like [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) and [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack). That means that, instead of keeping an `std::list` as an implementation detail, you could make the container type a template parameter and your `Quack` could then use any container supporting operations on both ends instead of begin stuck with `std::list`:

  ```
  template<
      typename T,
      typename Container = std::list<T>
  > class Quack
  {
      protected:
          // The name isn't great, but I chose the one used
          // by std::queue and std::stack
          Container c;

      public:
          using container_type = Container;
          using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
          using size_type = typename Container::size_type;
          using reference = typename Container::reference;
          using const_reference = typename Container::const_reference;
          using iterator = typename Container::iterator;
          using const_iterator = typename Container::const_iterator;

      // Here goes the rest of the implementation...
  };
  ```

  That design makes for a far more flexible `Quack` than what you had until there. Moreover, it won't surprise people used to the standard library container adapters.
- The name `poppop` is fun, but in practice `pop` would be enough and terser. Note that the standard library `pop` functions do not return a value and let `top`, `front` and `back` handle that for exception safety reasons. You might want to follow this design.
- Don't forget to `const-qualify` functions that to do alter your `Quack` so that you can also use them on a `const` quack instance:

  ```
  inline bool empty() const { return data.empty(); }
                      ^^^^^
  ```

  Note that I took the liberty to drop the stray semicolon at the end of the definition: it is not needed and your compiler would have warned you about it. I also added some spaces because I like to breath :)
- Generally speaking, it is not idiomatic for a class to have a `print` method in C++ since it binds it too tightly to a specific stream, in your case `std::cout`. The idiomatic way to make things displayable is to overload `operator<<` between `std::ostream&` and your class. Here is what it shoud look like:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Quack<T>& quack)
  {
      for (const T& elem: quack.data)
      {
          stream << elem << ' ';
      }
      stream << '\n';
      return stream;
  }
  ```

  Unless you expose the `Quack`'s iterators through `begin` and `end` methods, you will need to make this function a `friend` of `Quack`. Also, note that I changed `std::endl` to `'\n'`: it does not make that big of a difference, but `std::endl` might flush the stream (it depends on the stream) and your users might not want that. Let them add `std::flush` when they need to.

Comment: I have no idea what black magic they do to make a linear search a third faster, but I feel like it'd take me a while to understand.

Comment: @Yann A binary search is faster on random-access data. If you apply a binary search to `std::list`, it cannot "jump" from one position to another but has to go to there step by step (`std::distance` and `std::advance` are slow for `std::list`). A binary search is fast when it can jump, but if you can't jump it's easier to check your elements as you iterate, which is exacly what a linear search does.

Comment: I might have expressed that poorly. I meant that their linear search is about a third faster than my linear search, and I have no idea how one would go about optimising a for loop which checks everything, and breaks when you find it. I have now been thoroughly educated on that you should use a binary search on random-access data.

Comment: @Yann Sorry I misunderstood you then. I don't know why it's faster then. Maybe the compiler uses an intrinsic even if I doubt so.

Comment: @Yann Here you go for another round of comments, for the sake of it :)

Answer (score 3):

[`std::distance` is \$O(n)\$ when the iterator isn't random access](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/), so your algorithm is \$O(n \log n)\$.

In fact, [you cannot do a binary search on a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281053/how-to-apply-binary-search-olog-n-on-a-sorted-linked-list).

I would recommend to use a [Skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) instead, which sadly doesn't have a standard implementation.